# Criteria for selecting a library for Enterprise usage

Tags: frameworks, enterprise-library, enterprise, libraries

What are your criteria for selection a (open source) library (or framework) for enterprise usage?

Some libraries are pretty small and can be easily checked for security flaws or tested for performance. But most libraries are too big to be reviewed before you can start to use them.

When I think of me selecting a library, most if the selection process is just gut feeling. When I try to be more specific, these are the first criteria which come to my mind:

1. How many developers are working on the project? My feeling is that more developers will find more bugs and security issues. In addition it will be harder to introduce security issues intentionally.
2. How good is the support? Compared to closed source libraries, I've got the feeling that the support of open source is often much better since you have a community around the globe which will be available whenever you need them.
3. How wide spread is the library? Are there any books about it on the market? Which other projects are using the library?

What are your criteria? Feel free to edit this note as community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it depends on whether or not it is paid for or not.  In your case, you give the impression you are looking at open source libraries.

In that specific case, I'll look at test coverage.  Regardless of the number of contributors, if there aren't any unit tests that I can run myself (as well as enhance and test my use cases for if they fall outside the coverage of the unit tests provided), then that's a massive issue for me.

It's not that I don't appreciate the work that is done already in providing the library, but code in projects like this should have unit tests already with good coverage in order to gain traction.

If there are no libraries that have unit tests, then I would start searching for the library on search engines, actively seeking out negative replies.  People who have negative feelings about the code and can crystalize the objective basis for those feelings in terms of how the code failed them will provide more valuable feedback than the masses that say "it works great".

Now for a commercial piece of code, it's completely different.  At that point, I'd start looking at the company and it's support staff as a whole, and using that as a determination (as well as tests of your own to see if the library is right for you) as to whether or not to use that company's offering.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often in open source libraries you cannot get reliable support. In such situations your best bet is to fix it yourself, which involves the following requirements.

1. You need to have the ability to read often messy and undocumented code.
2. The technical ability to ask the right questions from the right people -- i.e., these people aren't being paid to fix problems and they will only answer you if you make it easy enough for them.
3. Then you need the ability to fix the bug and get the patch accepted -- because if the patch isn't accepted .....

With this in mind I would be inclined to get a commercial library, or dual licensed library so that I could pay to get a competent engineer (motivated by the money I pay his company) to fix my problem.